# Should twitter access token be stored?

Tags: twitter

It seems that after a user has connected to my twitter app, then in order to get any of his info or perform any actions, he must be redirected to twitter and then be redirected back to get a new oauth_verifier, before his info can be used in anything.

Therefore, is there any use for storing his access token when its returned?

Comment: Yes, you can store it, but store it in a safe place. That's how e. g. mobile apps do this.

Comment: if you are talking about `access_token`, you can since twitter do not set any expiry time for `access_token`.Here is the link for you https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#7188

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi What's the use of this access token though? Before I can get any info from twitter, I have to always redirect the user to twitter to get a new oauth_verifier before twitter lets me do anything

Comment: @ClickUpvote:`access_token` is like a key which is being given by twitter to you for accessing user data/profile on behalf of user.This is a key which you should get from twitter before accessing any data

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Can you post some code showing how to use this token? I'm following the method in [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/) , and before I can do anything, I must always redirect to twitter, get an oauth_verifier, then provide this oauth_verifier before I can do anything

Comment: @ClickUpvote:Sorry i have no idea about the PHP,but this redirection will happen every-time but you need not to worry as once a person authorize your application the next redirect will be so fast that no one will able to realize it and its a part of the specification.I can show you some example about same on Java

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Ok I see, thanks. But if it has to be redirected everytime, then there's no use of storing the access token in the database, right? Since each time it must be retrieved anyway.

Comment: no `access_token` is something you will get in last step so before that you will get only `request_token`

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Can you post your java code?

Comment: java.Moreover please remember redirecting and getting request_token is like authenticating user and you need not to go there every-time.it dependent upon your use-case,if you want to do some post/twitter update etc you can get access_token and can use it anytime without going to the twitter.redirecting there and coming back is a pouplar use case for providing third party login [Twitter Example] (https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/TwitterExample)

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Thanks, I get a 404 from your link though? Also if you post an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/TwitterExample.java.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Thanks.. however, what does this line do? ` Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());`. In my code, in order to get the verifier (which I assume means `oauth_verifier`) I must redirect the user to twitter, and on return, `oauth_verifier` is supplied as a URL parameter from twitter

Comment: that is just a way to get user input,the example is not a web-based one its for stand alone purpose so `in.nextLine()` is getting user input which will be the request_token being given by twitter.